# how to get windows device information in flutter using win32 api and wmi?

Tags: flutter, winapi, wmi, flutter-windows

I am trying to get windows machine information such as bios vendor, serial and other cpu info like cores, vendor, socket etc...(some static info).
I believe that I can achieve this using ffi and win32 api, but I don't have basic idea to start.
In other hand, [how get these details in flutter desktop application?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/027c7403-59ca-482a-a0b1-9bdfe0b273a9/win32-api-for-getting-system-information?forum=Vsexpressvc)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/027c7403-59ca-482a-a0b1-9bdfe0b273a9/win32-api-for-getting-system-information?forum=Vsexpressvc

Comment: I suggest you could start from the following Docs: 
[System Information Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/system-information-functions)
[Retrieving Device Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/retrieving-device-information)

Comment: Do you wish to get device information or do you wish to get device information using WMI?

Comment: I wish to get information using WMI, I found an easy way to do it, using PowerShell execution from the flutter. Please suggest if you have any better and easy options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a package to solve this, is [windows_info_device](https://github.com/Abdulazeezvp/windows_system_info) will help to get more details using WMI and PowerShell.